# How to price up-out-call by solving heat equation like down-out-call

Tags: derivatives, black-scholes-pde, barrier

We know that by changing the variables we can obtain the `Black-Scholes` formula of `vanilla call` through solving the `heat equation`:
$$S = Be^{x},\quad t = T - \tau/\dfrac{1}{2}\sigma^2,\quad C(t,S) = Bu(\tau, x),\quad v(\tau,x)=e^{\alpha x+\beta\tau}u(\tau,x)$$
$$\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial \tau} = \dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}$$
with boundary and initial conditions:
$$v(\tau,x)=0, x\rightarrow -\infty;$$
$$v(\tau,x)\sim (e^x-e^{-r\tau}), x\rightarrow \infty;$$
$$v(0,x) = u_0(x).$$
And, for the `down-out-call`, only the boundary conditions change:
$$v(\tau,x)=0, x=0;$$
$$v(\tau,x)\sim (e^x-e^{-r\tau}), x\rightarrow \infty;$$
$$x\in(0,\infty)$$
then we can use the `reflection property` of `heat equation`

Let
$$v(\tau,x) = V(\tau,x)-V(\tau,-x)$$
here $V(\tau,x)$ is the solution in the first `vanilla call heat equation`, to extend $v(\tau,x)$ to $x\in(-\infty,\infty);$

But, for the `up-out-call`, the boundary conditions become:
$$v(\tau,x)=0, x\rightarrow-\infty;$$
$$v(\tau,x)=0,x=0;$$
$$x\in(-\infty,0)$$
I don't how to use $V(\tau,x)$ to construct the above conditions(surely, include the initial condition)？

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to omit is the initial condition for $v(\tau, x)$? Assume you have an up-and-out barrier option for which $v$ satisfies the initial boundary value problem

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{H} \{ v \} (\tau, x) & = & 0 \qquad \text{for } (\tau, x) \in \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}_-\\
v(0, x) & = & f(x)\\
v(\tau, 0) & = & 0 \qquad \text{for } \tau \in [0, \infty).
\end{eqnarray}

Here, $\mathcal{H}$ is the heat equation operator and $f(x)$ is the payoff specific initial condition - in your case that of a call option. Then you define the auxiliary initial value problem $V(\tau, x)$ which satisfies

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{H} \{ V \} (\tau, x) & = & 0 \qquad \text{for } (\tau, x) \in \left( \mathbb{R}_+, \mathbb{R} \right)\\
V(0, x) & = & f(x) \mathrm{1} \{ x < 0 \}.
\end{eqnarray}

$V(\tau, x)$ is the corresponding full-range problem where you keep the initial condition but restrict it to the active domain of the barrier option via the indicator. You solve for $V(\tau, x)$ by e.g. a convolution of the initial condition with the heat kernel.

Comment: so, how to solve my question?

Comment: So your problem is that you don't know what $f(x)$ in my above notation is for a call option?

Comment: sorry, you may misunderstand my point, I mean how to use $V(\tau, x)$ to construct the boundary condition $v(\tau,x)=0,\ x\rightarrow -\infty.$, we know like `down-out` $v(\tau,x)=V(\tau,x)-V(\tau,-x)$ is not true for `up-out` case.